# How to pass data onclose to parent in $mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I open a `Dialog Window` (which has it's `own controller`).
I want to change data in `differentController` that belongs to `Dialog Window` and `onRemoving` send data back to `parent controller` and apply data. Is it possible?

```
function openTaskDialog(ev, test)
{
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller         : 'differentController',
        controllerAs       : 'vm',
        templateUrl        : 'dialog.html',
        parent             : angular.element($document.body),
        targetEvent        : ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        onComplete: onComplete,
        onRemoving: function (event, promise) {
            console.log('onRemoving',event, promise, $mdDialog)
        },
        locals             : {
            Test : test,
            event: ev

        }
    })
    .finally(function(){
    })
}

function onComplete (scope, el, options) {
    console.log('scope, el, options', scope, el, options)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call the `$mdDialog.hide([response]);` function on the controller of the dialog, this `[response]` is passed as an parameter to the promise returned by the `$mdDialog.show()` function.

If you call the `$mdDialog.hide([response]);` the promise will be resolved, if you call `$mdDialog.cancel([response]);` the promise will be rejected.

```
function openTaskDialog(ev, test)
{
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller         : 'differentController',
        controllerAs       : 'vm',
        templateUrl        : 'dialog.html',
        parent             : angular.element($document.body),
        targetEvent        : ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        onComplete: onComplete,
        onRemoving: function (event, promise) {
            console.log('onRemoving',event, promise, $mdDialog)
        },
        locals             : {
            Test : test,
            event: ev

        }
    }).then(function(response){

    })
    .catch(function(responseIfRejected){

    })
    .finally(function(){
    })

}

function onComplete (scope, el, options) {
    console.log('scope, el, options', scope, el, options)
}

function differentController($mdDialog){
    this.save = function(){
        $mdDialog.hide({ message: 'success' });
    };
    this.cancel = function(){
        $mdDialog.cancel({ message: 'fail' });
    };
}
```